# Django custom template tags: ImportError for packaged app

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am writing custom template tags, for a reusable django app.
The tag I am defining is referencing a model in the same app, so i need to import it.

Everything works fine if I copy my app code into a django project, but if I package my app with distutils and install it via pip or setup.py install (so the app code gets copied in site-packages), I cannot use it.

When trying to import my application models in the template tags module, i get an ImportError.
Code raising the error is this:

> from django import template
>   import cms_fragments.models
>
> register = template.Library()

Exception raised is this:

> ImportError raised loading cms_fragments.templatetags.cms_fragments_tags: No module named models

I am pretty sure that my application layout is correct:

> |-cms_fragments
>
> > |-**_*init*_**.py
> >     |-models.py
> >     |-templatetags
> >
> > > |-**_*init*_**.py
> > >       |-cms_fragments_tags.py
> > >       |-views.py

I have seen all posts related to this, but I never found anyone reporting this difference between an app with code living in the django-project versus code living in site-packages.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you are importing/using the library you want. It should work if you import "models" like this:

```
from cms_fragments import models
```

But it will be better if you post the piece of code where you use this "models" package, because i'm just guessing how did you use it. Reading the error you got, it seems to be that you are trying to reference "models" module like this:

```
models.some_thing_inside_models...
```

but as you import like this:

```
import cms_fragments.models
```

you must reference it this way:

```
cms_fragments.models.some_thing_inside_models...
```

[Here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) is some documentation that may help you and that explains well how to work with your proyect directory tree.